# Exclude values within a range for rowsum in R

Tags: r, dataframe, logarithm, rowsum

I'm trying to get the row sums for each row of my dataframe but with a condition. I'd like to exclude all the values that are between -1 and 1 after applying log2. I know how to exclude NAs but I'm confused with excluding actual numbers. My dataframe is just numbers, except for the row and column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 dat1 <- dat
 dat1[dat1 >-1  & dat1<1] <- NA
 rowSums(dat1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If there are no `NAs` in the dataset, you could assign the values to 0 and just use `rowSums`

```
 dat1[dat1 >-1  & dat1<1] <- 0
 rowSums(dat1)
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(42)
 dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(-5,5,by=0.25), 20*5,
                           replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'll accept the answer in five minutes